# Add click to see details in pricing table

Tags: php, css, laravel

I have some pricing tables that I would like to hide part of it and reveal on click, the code generates multiple pricing tables but when I try to apply the click to reveal it only applies to the first table, how can I apply it to all the tables generated?
Here:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 20px;">
                <div class="single-price-table table-active wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.6s" style="border-radius: 50px;">

                    <div class="pricing-head">
                        <h4 class="pricing-title">{{ $pl->name }}</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="pricing-content">

                        <div class="pricing-value-wrapper" >
                            <div class="plan-pricing-description">
                            @if($pl->price_type == 0)
                                <h2 class="pricing-value">
                                    FREE
                                    @if($pl->plan_type == 0)
                                        <sub>/ {{$pl->duration}} days</sub>
                                    @else
                                        <sub>/ unlimited</sub>
                                    @endif

                                </h2>
                            @else
                                <h2 class="pricing-value">
                                    <sup>{{ $basic->currency }}</sup>
                                    {{ $pl->price }}
                                    @if($pl->plan_type == 0)
                                        <sub>/ {{$pl->duration}} days</sub>
                                    @else
                                        <sub>/ unlimited</sub>
                                    @endif
                                </h2>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul class="table-content">
                            <li>{{ $pl->main_description }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $pl->sub_description }}</li>
                            <li>Dashboard Signal - {{ $pl->dashboard_status == 1 ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}</li>
                            <li>Email Alert - {{ $pl->email_status == 1 ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}</li>
                            <li>Telegram Alert - {{ $pl->telegram_status == 1 ? 'YES' : 'NO' }}</li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                    <div class="pricibg-footer">
                        <a href="{{ route('auth.register-plan',$pl->id) }}" class="button button-small">Subscribe
                            now</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You can do it with JS only

Comment: Any help on how can I do it? I did it a while ago with some js but it still only applied to the first generated pricing table